# python append folder name to filenames in all sub folders

Tags: python, file-processing

I am trying to append the name of a folder to all filenames within that folder. I have to loop through a parent folder that contain sub folders. I have to do this in Python and not a bat file.

Example is, take these folders:

```
Parent Folder
 Sub1
  example01.txt
  example01.jpg
  example01.tif
 Sub2
  example01.txt
  example01.jpg
  example01.tif
```

To this

```
Parent Folder
 Sub1
  Sub1_example01.txt
  Sub1_example01.jpg
  Sub1_example01.tif
 Sub2
  Sub2_example01.txt
  Sub2_example01.jpg
  Sub2_example01.tif
```

I believe its os.rename, but i cant work out how to call the folder name.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You can use `os.walk` to go through the directory and get the names of the files and then `os.rename` to change the names. SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: `os.walk` will give me the filenames in a folder, but it wont give me the name of the folder. If i understood it correctly.

Comment: this might help http://techs.studyhorror.com/python-get-last-directory-name-in-path-i-139

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use `os.path.basename` on the root to find your prefix.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Parent"):
    if not files:
        continue
    prefix = os.path.basename(root)
    for f in files:
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, "{}_{}".format(prefix, f)))
```

Before

```
> tree Parent
Parent
├── Sub1
│   ├── example01.jpg
│   ├── example02.jpg
│   └── example03.jpg
└── Sub2
    ├── example01.jpg
    ├── example02.jpg
    └── example03.jpg

2 directories, 6 files
```

After

```
> tree Parent
Parent
├── Sub1
│   ├── Sub1_example01.jpg
│   ├── Sub1_example02.jpg
│   └── Sub1_example03.jpg
└── Sub2
    ├── Sub2_example01.jpg
    ├── Sub2_example02.jpg
    └── Sub2_example03.jpg

2 directories, 6 files
```

Comment: Works perfectly.

For others not familiar, the "Parent" should have double path spaces, e.g. C:\\test\\dir1

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk) to iterate over the directories and then [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.rename) to rename all the files:

```
from os import walk, path, rename

for dirpath, _, files in walk('parent'):
    for f in files:
        rename(path.join(dirpath, f), path.join(dirpath, path.split(dirpath)[-1] + '_' + f))
```